# Make a Copy of a Google Spreadhseet retaining all formats but copy only values

Tags: copy, spreadsheet

I need to create a monthly archive of a scorecard spreadsheet. The archived file must retain all the formatting (borders, colours, col width etc) but only have the values. In other words, no formulas must copy across, only the results.

I am currently able to make a copy of the spreadsheet and append a date to the name but all the formulas are copied across as well. To do this I use the following code that is called from a UI:

```
function archiveSC(e){
  var archiveExtension = " "+e.parameter.archiveExt;
  var root = DocsList.getRootFolder()
  var archiveFolder = DocsList.getFolder('Scorecard Archives');
  var archiveFile = DocsList.getFileById(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId()).makeCopy(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName() + archiveExtension);
  archiveFile.addToFolder(archiveFolder);
  archiveFile.removeFromFolder(root);

  var archiveApp = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  archiveApp.close()
  return archiveApp;
```

Is there any function or code that I can add to ensure that all formats are copied and only the values.

Comment: I guess I could. This would be a 2 stage copy get the final result. Am I correct?